# what is the difference between following equality checks?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(5 == new Integer(5)) output = true

Integer i31 = 2;
Integer i32 = new Integer(2);
System.out.println(i31 == i32); output = false
```

It rather seems since we are in function scope. hence different output.
Unable to grasp what can be different.

Comment: `int==Integer` does value comparison. `Integer==Integer` does reference comparison.

Comment: try `((int) i31) == i32` or `((Integer) 5) == new Integer(5)` - it's about (auto)boxing and unboxing and comparison of primitives and of references